# redux-saga - how to deal with API method that invokes callback many times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback, react-redux, redux-saga

I have external API that has a method like this
`watchForEvents(callback)`, where `callback` should be a function `function(result, error) {...}`.
Callback invoked many times - one time for the each event produced by the API. Method `watchForEvents` is non-blocking.

I have a React.JS app that uses `redux-saga`. I can not figure out how to deal with such API.

If I invoke API method and make delay in my saga - everything works. I.e. `yield call(delay, 10000);`. But without delay saga swallows all invocations of the callback.

What can I do with this?

Answer (score 3):

Redux saga [channels](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/blob/master/docs/advanced/Channels.md) are great for such situations, for example

```
import { eventChannel, END } from "redux-saga";
import { call, put, take } from "redux-saga/effects";

function yourChannel(action) {
  return eventChannel(emitter => {
    watchForEvents(function(result, error) {
      if (error) {
        throw new Error(error);
      } else {
        emitter(result);
      }
    });
  });
}

function* yourSaga(action) {
  const chan = yield call(yourChannel, action);
  try {
    while (true) {
      const result = yield take(chan);
      console.log(result); // will log on every event
    }
  } catch (err) {
    // catch error here
  } finally {
    // if you do emitter(END) inside your channel, you know here that the channel has terminated
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had some experience on this one, and what I did was to create an event emitter that would emit an event for every invoke on my callback function. And then on redux-saga, it's just a matter of creating an event channel around that event emitter.

I have created a sample gist of my approach, with my use case before. Hope it could help: https://gist.github.com/aamiel16/75c1cd3fd1d9ef873a88dcf4dd86e00d

If there are any questions around it, I would be happy to follow up an answer on them.